# How to generate all permutations of the flattened list of lists?

Tags: python, list, permutation, combinatorics, nested-lists

How to generate all permutations of the flattened list of lists in Python, ... such that the order in the lists is maintained?

Example;

input;

```
[[1,2], [3]]
```

output;

```
[1,2,3]
[1,3,2]
[3,1,2]
```

1 is always before 2 in the permutations.

Comment: Take a look at [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: Could you please explain better how the output should be generated?

Comment: All of you thanks very much for thinking with me. 2 solutions filter out of all possible permutations. As the number of permutations run with n! this isn't practical. For instance with the input [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]] we already have 15!=13 biljon permutations. We know that valid permutations must start with either 1,2,4,7,11 rendering already 2/3 of the permutations invalid. The networkx solution produces an iterator very fast. I lack the knowledge to check if it is correct.

Comment: 15!=1.3 trillion, sorry

Comment: Counting the 37837800 permutations produced by the @RaySteam networkx based algorithm, with [[1,2], [3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15]] as input, ran for almost 41 minutes.

Comment: for index in range(37837800):pass runs in seconds.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you could model this as finding all topological sorts in a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), so I suggest you use networkx, for example:

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx

data = [[1,2], [3]]
edges = [edge for ls in data for edge in zip(ls, ls[1:])]

# this creates a graph from the edges (e.g. [1, 2])
dg = nx.DiGraph(edges)

# add all the posible nodes (e.g. {1, 2, 3})
dg.add_nodes_from(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data)))

print(list(nx.all_topological_sorts(dg)))
```

**Output**

```
[[3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2]]
```

For the input provided, the following DiGraph is created:

```
Nodes: [1, 2, 3], Edges: [(1, 2)]
```

A [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) imposes the constraint that `1` is always going to be present before `2`. More on all topological sortings can be found, [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.all_topological_sorts.html).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem; I'm not sure whether there is a builtin in itertools for this, but this would seem to work:

### Code:

```
l = [[1,2], [3]]

# Create list containing indexes of sublists by the number of elements in that
# sublist - in this case [0, 0, 1]
l2 = [y for i, x in enumerate(l) for y in [i]*len(x)]

rv = []

# For every unique permutation of l2:
for x in set(itertools.permutations(l2)):
    l = [[1,2], [3]]
    perm = []
    # Create a permutation from l popping the first item of a sublist when
    # we come across that sublist's index
    for i in x:
        perm.append(l[i].pop(0))
    rv.append(tuple(perm))
```

### Output:

```
>>> rv
[(3, 1, 2), (1, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the permutations generator, filter by checking that all input sublists are sublists of the permutations. Sublist function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964184/10020283).

```py
l = [[1,2], [3]]

def sublist(lst1, lst2):
   ls1 = [element for element in lst1 if element in lst2]
   ls2 = [element for element in lst2 if element in lst1]
   return ls1 == ls2

[perm for perm in itertools.permutations(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
 if all(sublist(l_el, perm) for l_el in l)]

[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (3, 1, 2)]
```