# How do I check to see if a nested list is in another list, regardless of order

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists, tic-tac-toe

I'm making tic-tac-toe in python. I have a board, and each of the squares corresponds to a number (0-8) and to help with win conditions, I have this list:

```
wins = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Whenever one of the players puts down a letter, wherever they placed the letter gets put into a list, so at the end of the game one of their lists might look like this:

```
player1 = [0, 1, 4, 5, 6]
```

How do I check if all of the elements of one of the nested lists are in player1 (regardless of order, if possible)?

Comment: `any(all(position in player1 for position in win) for win in wins)`, checks if there is `any` win condition for which `all` actions (positions) are in `player1`. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964155/checking-if-list-is-a-sublist) post for checking sublists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to check if any of the possible winning square lists is equivalent to player1's selected square list, you can do

```
any([set(w) == set(player1) for w in wins])
```

However, it seems to me that it would make more sense to check if any of the winning square lists are *contained* within player1's moves, meaning not necessarily **all** of the elements are in player1. You can do this by simply doing

```
any([set(w).issubset(set(player1)) for w in wins])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `all` function which checks if a list is a subset of another list. See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

For example:

```
def check_for_win():
    for win in wins:
        if all(x in player1 for x in win):
            return True
    return False
```