# How to check if a list (string) contains another list (string) considering order

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, sequence

I have two list (or string): one is big, and the other one is small.
I want to check whether the bigger one (A) contains the small one (B) or not.

My expectation is as follows:

Case 1. B is a subset of A

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [1,2] 
contains(A, B) = True
```

Case 2. B is not a subset of A, but order [1,2] is maintained in A

```
A = [1,3,2]
B = [1,2]
contains(A, B) = True
```

Case 3. False because 4 in not A

```
A = [1,3,2]
B = [1,4]
contains(A, B) = False
```

Case 4. False because the order [2,1] not maintained in A, even though A contains 1 and 2.

```
A = [1,3,2]
B = [2,1]
contains(A, B) = False
```

A and B could be string.

Comment: Do the lists have duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964184/13357878) should work if you just don't remove things from the sublist that aren't in the test list. So for the case of the first method provided there

```py
def contains(testList, subList):
   shared = [x for x in testList if x in subList]
   return shared == subList
```

You could also convert the sublist to work with non-list inputs.

```py
def contains(testList, subList):
   shared = [x for x in testList if x in subList]
   return shared == list(subList)
```

Comment: Would this still work if there were duplicates in `testList`? I think then there would be duplicates in `shared` as well, and the lists wouldn't necessarily compare equal.

Comment: This is `O(NM)` instead of `O(N+M)`, and fails for duplicates, e.g. "batman" contains "bam", but this function would return False

Answer (score 1):

### Direct Imperative Approach

I'm pretty sure checking whether one list is a sublist of another is a classic greedy algorithm. We can scan the larger list, trying to find each item in the smaller list in order. We never need to backtrack, because the first occurrence of each element is fine.

```py
def contains(larger, smaller):
  # Take an iterator so that we always pick up where we left off.
  larger_iter = iter(larger)
  for s in smaller:
    for l in larger_iter:
      if s == l:
        break
    else:
      # We'll enter the else block if we *didn't* break in the loop,
      # in which case we never found a match for s.
      return False
  return True
```

This will run linear in the size of the larger list, because we iterate it at most once.

### Functional Approach

**Edit.** I wondered last night if there were a smaller (line-wise) solution that was still linear, and I have one now that I like.

```py
def contains(larger, smaller):
  larger_iter = iter(larger)
  return all(s in larger_iter for s in smaller)
```

This is following the exact same algorithm as above, just using a higher-level function to handle some of the bookkeeping. `s in larger_iter` corresponds to the inner for-loop with else block, and `all` with generator corresponds to the outer for-loop.

Comment: This answer is correct and efficient, which is more than I can say about all other existing answers (including the accepted one)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your lists into `set()` groups. Example :

```
A = set(A)
B = set(B)
print(A <= B)
```

You can subset `a <= b` method. Good workings

Comment: I'm guessing `B <= A` would be what @GilseungAhn wants in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't this ignore order? As in OP's last example with `[2, 1]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.deque` for an `O(n)` solution:

```
from collections import deque
def contains(a, b):
  b = deque(b)
  for i in a:
     if b and i == b[0]:
        _ = b.popleft()
  return not bool(b)

data = [([1, 2, 3], [1, 2]), ([1, 3, 2], [1, 2]), ([1, 3, 2], [1, 4]), ([1, 3, 2], [2, 1])]
print([contains(*i) for i in data])
```

Output

```
[True, True, False, False]
```