# Check if list is sublist of another list and the elements are in the same order

Tags: python

```
#sub list test 1
a = [1,1,2]
b = [0, 1,1,1,2,1]

#sub list test 2
c = [4,5]
d = [2,3,4,5,6]
```

```
if all(i in a for i in b):
   print("Yes I have all the elements but not sure about their order :( ")
```

I have tried `all()` or using `counter()` from `collections` module. I can't seem to figure it out how to check their order too.

Comment: If the first elements match, what else is left to do?  If they don't what else is left to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if list is a sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964155/checking-if-list-is-a-sublist)

Comment: @sj95126 - No, the solution there doesn't check order. You can test that on first test above (a and b)

Comment: @Danny: there are many solutions in that thread. Some do not check order and the comments reflect that.

Comment: Sublist already implies same order. So it's unclear what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will check all subList of length a and return True if a is found in b

Not sure about order :

```py
def isSublist(a,b):
    #checking all unique elements and their count
    for i in set(a):
        if i not in b or a.count(i) > b.count(i):
             return False
    return True
```

Sure about order :

```py
def isSublist(a,b):
    for i in range(len(b)-len(a)+1):
        if b[i:i+len(a)] == a:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: It looks good. I'll do some more tests and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I have done more tests and it's working as expected. cheers

Comment: Your first code could be `return Counter(a) <= Counter(b)`

Comment: @Dennis we cannot compare 2 Counter objects it gives a type error check your self once

Comment: Why not? `Counter("abc") <= Counter("abbbc")` returns True, and does the same job as the "not sure about order" code block above.

Comment: @Dennis please try running it , Counter is gonna return a Counter object which is similar to a dictionary so you are saying we can compare 2 dictionaries directly?

Comment: Ah I see, that feature was added in Python 3.10, and won't work in prior versions.

Comment: yeah its working in python 3.10

Comment: @AlainT. I refer consecutive when I mention order

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, when elements of lists has normal types, you can just **convert them to str first** and then do

```
"#".join(sublist) in "#".join(list)
```

Where `#` is a symbol that doesn't occur in `list`

Edit, as **no comment** pointed out, indeed there is one bug it that approach - if last sublists element is prefix of last lists element. Same with first element suffix. We can manage it by adding some kind of sentinel at the beggining/end, so correct solution would be

```
"#".join([""] + sublist + [""]) in "#".join([""] + list + [""])
```

Comment: `join` won't work if the list elements aren't `str`

Comment: @match I touched that in answer ;) The problem is sometimes simple `str` method can not be enough (e.g. for class with custom __eq__) that's why I provided last step of algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use all() by performing the check for membership of `a` in `b` through an iterator on `b`:

```
a = [1,1,2]
b = [0, 1,1,1,2,1]

r = all(n in ib for ib in [iter(b)] for n in a)
print(r) # True
```

It will also find a match for items in the same relative order (that are not consecutive):

```
a=[1,2,1]
b=[1,2,3,1]
r = all(n in ib for ib in [iter(b)] for n in a)
print(r) # True
```

How it works:

- every time `n in ib` is executed, the `ib` iterator advances up to the next matching value in `b`.
- Going through all values of `a` will match items sequentially over the remainder of `b` after each match check
- If `ib` is exhausted before getting to the end of `a`, then the elements aren't all present or their order doesn't match

If you are looking for **consecutive matches**, you can use the `in` operator on a generator that yields sublists of the corresponding length:

```
a = [1,1,2]
b = [0, 1,1,1,2,1]

r = a in (b[i:i+len(a)] for i in range(len(b)-len(a)+1))
print(r) # True
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and the explanation. I need to go through it at my pace as I am new to Python.