# How to check if a string is only made-up from a list of words?

Tags: python, string

I have a list of words:

```
words = ['ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG']
```

How to check that my string only consists words from that list? For example, `'EFG CDE'` results `True` since both `'CDE'` and `'EFG'` are in `words`.

My code is below:

```
lmn = []
for j in list(itertools.permutations(words, 2)) + list(itertools.permutations(words, 3)):
    lmn.append(' '.join(j))

'EFG CDE' in lmn
```

My output is giving `True` which is correct.

But for strings like `'EFG EFG CDE'`, `'CDE CDE CDE CDE'` it will not give `True` because these strings are not present in `lmn`. Even if they are made of the list `['ABC', 'CDE', 'EFG']` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
allowed_words = set(['ABC','CDE','EFG'])
target_string = 'EFG EFG CDE'
print(all(word in allowed_words for word in target_string.split()))
```

Comment: can you check below test  `allowed_words = set(['ABC','CDE','EFG'])
target_string = 'EFG EFG cde'
print(all(word.lower() in allowed_words for word in target_string.lower().split()))` I am getting False instead of True

Comment: You would need to apply the `.lower()` transformation to `allowed_words` as well.  But since those words are already all uppercase, you could just swap `.lower()` for `.upper()` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to build every possible permutation and then checking (which will be unbounded if the input is unbounded), just do the search yourself.

The problem is 'check every component part of the string is present in an iterable' where component part is defined as 'part separated by a space':

```py
def check_string_made_of_parts(candidate, parts):
    return all(part in parts for part in candidate.split(" "))
```

With these kind of problems in python it's helpful to talk through a sensible algorithm in words before you hit any code.

Answer (score 0):

If you break down your problem, you have a list (could be a set?) of *allowed* words and a string made up of words.

You want to check that every word in your string is in the list of allowed words. Translated loosely, you want to check that *the set of words in your string **is a subset** of the set of allowed words*.

Now there are two steps:

1. [Get the set of words from the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181763/converting-a-string-to-a-list-of-words).
2. [Check if it is a subset of the allowed words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964155/checking-if-list-is-a-sublist).

(1) is quite easy - `words = set(s.split())`

(2) can be done by using basic [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) operations:

```
words.issubset(allowed_words)  # allowed_words doesn't need to be a set
words <= set(allowed_words)
```

Comment: can you check below test allowed_words = set(['ABC','CDE','EFG']) target_string = 'EFG EFG cde' print(all(word.lower() in allowed_words for word in target_string.lower().split())) I am getting False instead of True

Comment: Not sure why you commented here as I propose this solution, but it would make more sense to be: `print(all(word.upper() in allowed_words for word in target_string.split()))`